# Get data FormData

Tags: php, jquery

I have a text field and an image in form so I get this in jquery

```
var formData = new FormData("form")[0];
```

Send by ajax formData

how do i get the text field data and the image in php?

```
$data = $_POST['formData'];
```

Comment: In php, file uploads appear in $_FILES. You can read about this in the documentation already